# Handle Ajax Auto Suggest Drop List using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to enter value to the From field of http://busindia.com/ using the following code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("matchFromPlace")).sendKeys("Udupi");
```

while typing `udupi` in the from input there appears a list of options beneath from which we select to select `udupi`.

Comment: i am unable to select the xpath of the auto suggest droplist , i am using google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> OptionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]/li/a"));
    if(OptionList.size()>=1){
        for(int i=0;i<OptionList.size();i++)
        {
            String CurrentOption = OptionList.get(i).getText();
            if(CurrentOption.equalsIgnoreCase("UDUPI")){
                System.out.println("Found the city : "+CurrentOption);
                OptionList.get(i).click();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("OptionList is empty");
    }
```

Comment: thank you it is working . can you tell me how you got the xpath //ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]/li/a , as i am unable to select the drop down to inspect it . i am using chrome driver

Comment: Even I'm using chrome driver. I'm able to right-click on the drop-down to inspect it.
"@class,'ui-autocomplete''" - This is what a have observed in most of the dynamic drop-downs over internet.
Please mark answer as accepted, if you like it! :)

Answer (score 1):

please try below code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
action.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Ajaxcontrol {

public WebDriver driver;


@Test()

public void f () throws Exception { 

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys("selenium");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnK']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String str=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='erkvQe']")).getText();

            System.out.println(str);

             String[] s= str.split("\n");
                System.out.println(s.length);

                        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{

                                if(s[i].equalsIgnoreCase("selenium tutorial"))
         {
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).clear();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys(s[i]);
           Thread.sleep(5000);

           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Selenium Tutorial for Beginners: Learn WebDriver i')]")).click();
         }
}


}


@BeforeTest

public void beforeTest() {

    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium DriverFiles\\chromedriver.exe");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium DriverFiles\\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Selenium DriverFiles\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}


@AfterTest

public void afterTest() {

    driver.quit();
}
}
```